# will apple Reject app that has only login

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have a application that provide the user to download employee contacts for the client (company) . i give each client (company) a user name and password to distrebute it to his employees to download employees contact in his company .
so i havent a sign up screen ,only i have a login screen 
will apple reject it Or Not , will it consider that lock feature and use external in-app purchase .

Comment: You need a sign up screen. Otherwise your App will be rejected. like in Evernote if you don't have an account you signup in the app and then get access to everything. Tell me in the comments for any more Explaining :)

Comment: Does your app doing anything else besides allow a user to download a file? Your app will probably be rejected for not doing anything useful or for being something that should be done as a simple website.

Comment: i was upload it and rejected , but i was use a shortcode .
apple reject it because
We found your app inappropriately unlocks or enables additional functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

It may be appropriate to revise your app to use the In App Purchase API to provide content purchasing functionality.

Comment: then i ask apple to help and told to me that
You may wish to implement username/password type of authentication instead of requiring a code.

Comment: The Login screen is not the issue. I have an app in the store where you have to login for full access and you cannot sign in in the app (but on a web site). In those cases Apple requests login credentials for a test user. They introduced fields for username and passwort in the iTunes Connect portal for that pupose. (Before that it was to be handed using the comments field). However I donnot know anything about the other issue.

Comment: thanks Hermann Klecker ,
so i can only implement a login screen . and the sign up will be through web

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments and question Apple could reject your app on following terms(from the review guide):

> 2.12 Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may
>   be rejected.

or

> 2.22 Apps that arbitrarily restrict which users may use the App, such as by location or carrier, may be rejected.

Since you're not providing the possibility to make an account, not even on an external website (you said you already distributed the credentials) thus not offering any viable content to the public.

Other than that, there is no reason to reject an app that only shows a login screen. But this is just speculation, it could as well pass without a problem.

Did you consider the [enterprise program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/)?

Answer (score 3):

No problem! I have you send your app to Apple you need to give them a test login.